# Sorting out gap between div and footer

Tags: css, html

I have a few questions regarding my DIV layout.

I can't seem to understand why [my layout](http://jsfiddle.net/methuselah/V44Jw/1/) has a massive gap between the divs and the footer. How can I get it to line up right underneath the footer?

Secondly it seems that the method used to make **box 2,3,4** all correlate height-wise (they seem to be a bit skew at the bottom). How do I accomplish this? Right now I'm just doing a bit of guess work with the height percentages.

Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="logo">logo</div>

    <div id="header">
        <a href="#">link 1</a>
        &nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a href="#">link 2</a>
        &nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a href="#">link 3</a>
        &nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a href="#">link 4</a>
    </div>

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

    <div class="column" id="first-column">
        <div class="window" id="window-1">1</div>
        <div class="window" id="window-2">2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="column" id="second-column">
        <div class="window" id="window-3">3</div>
    </div>


    <div class="column" id="third-column">
        <div class="window" id="window-4">4</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

​

CSS:

```
body, html{
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1212px;
    min-height: 540px;
    min-width: 784px;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

#header{
    text-align:right;
    padding:5px;
    font-size:10px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

#first-column{
    width: 20%;
    padding-left: 5px;
    height: 100%;
}

#second-column{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

#third-column{
    width: 25%;
}

.window{
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border:1px solid #CECECE;
    width:100%;
}

#window-1{
    height:43.5%;
}

#window-2{
    margin-top:10px;
    height:43.5%;
}

#window-3{
    height:87%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#window-4{
    height:87%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.column{
    float:left;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 100%;
}

.logo {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.footer {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Check out this "holy grail" 3-column layout. http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`height:100%` makes trouble, you should remove it first.